# Looking for eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm getting a bit confused here. I think I was told that all $n\times n$ matrices had eigenvalues, but to me the following matrix seems suspicious:
\begin{bmatrix}
    4 && 5 \\
    -5 && -4
\end{bmatrix}

Looking for the eigenvalue, we get the following:
$\begin{bmatrix}
    4-\lambda && 5 \\
    -5 && -4-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}$

And calculating the determinant:
$\begin{vmatrix}
    4-\lambda && 5 \\
    -5 && -4-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
= (4-\lambda)(-4-\lambda)+25=0$

This yields roots of $\pm3i$:

$$(4-\lambda)(-4-\lambda)+25=0$$
$$(4-\lambda)(-4-\lambda) = -25$$
$$-16-4\lambda+4\lambda+\lambda^2 = -25$$
$$-16+\lambda^2 = -25$$
$$\lambda^2 = -9$$
$$\lambda = \pm3i$$

Am I doing something wrong, or is that $\lambda$?

Comment: Your result is fine.

Comment: Try with $$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 && 1 \\
    -1 && 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ The characteristic polynomial is $t^2+1=0$. So the eigenvalues need not be real. Still, every matrix has eigenvalues. The point is "where".

Comment: Why are you suspicious about that result?

Comment: Okay, but then what are the eigenvectors?

Comment: Eigenvectors are a different problem, but you will get complex eigenvectors in this case. Trust your gut; it works exactly the same as the real case

Comment: @meszolym You can evaluate them in the usual way, maybe the will be complex.

Comment: please calculate $$   \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
4 & 5 \\ 
-5 & -4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)     \left( 
\begin{array}{c} 
5  \\ 
-4 + 3 i  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
   $$

Comment: They all have eigenvalues if u work in $\mathbb{C}$ (because its algebraically closed), however if you work in the field of real numbers there are matrices that indeed have no eigenvalues (take the matrix of a rotation by $90$ degree, its geometrically obvious it doesnt have any real eigenvalue). It's characteristic polynomial is $X^2+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $n \times n$ matrix $A$, the equation $\det(A - \lambda I_n) = 0$ is an $n$-degree polynomial, so it always has $n$ solutions - but there is no guarantee that they are all distinct, nor are they all guaranteed to be real.

It is not uncommon to have complex-valued eigenvalues, even for matrices containing only real entries. In that case, the eigenvalues will come in pairs of complex conjugates (i.e. you'll have pairs of the form $a \pm bi$), and the eigenvectors will also wind up having imaginary components. For example, for the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, the characteristic equation is $\det \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda & -1 \\ 1 & \lambda\end{pmatrix} = 0 \implies \lambda^2 + 1 = 0$ so the eigenvalues are $\lambda = \pm i$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \mp i \end{pmatrix}$. You can verify that pretty easily, for example:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -i \end{pmatrix} & = & \begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
& = & i \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -i \end{pmatrix} \end{eqnarray}$$